# Hide or show CheckBox in CustomAdapter

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, custom-adapter

I'm using databse in my app. I can create some "notes" , and define the type : Homework or Test.

Then I display it in a ListView.
But, when the row is created, I'd like to check if I chose "Homework" as the type, and if I did, I add a checkbox to that row in my listView, but If I chose "Test", I do not display the CheckBox.

Then, with the checkbox I can set the homework as DONE or NOT DONE with the cb.isChecked(). But first I have to only display the checkBox if it's a homework. But I don't know how to check it..

How can I do that ?

Here's my CustomAdapter class

```
public class CustomAdapterJalons extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

private Context mContext;
private Context appContext;
private int layout;
private Cursor cr;
private final LayoutInflater inflater;

public CustomAdapterJalons(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to) {
    super(context, layout, c, from, to);
    this.layout = layout;
    this.mContext = context;
    this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.cr = c;
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    return inflater.inflate(layout, null);
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, final Context context, final Cursor cursor) {
    super.bindView(view, context, cursor);

    LinearLayout root_view = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.item_root);

    root_view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            //method
        }
    });

   final int position = cursor.getPosition();

    cursor.moveToPosition(position);

    int devoir = cursor.getInt(3);
    int evaluation = cursor.getInt(4);
    CheckBox cbdevoir = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.CBDevoir);


    if(devoir==1)
    {
     cbdevoir.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
   if(evaluation==1)
   {
       cbdevoir.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
   }
    }
```

}

Thank you guys !

Comment: you have to add condition to check that current position data is homework or test if homework set visibility of checkbox to VISIBLE else set to GONE/INVISIBLE

Comment: How do I do that ?

Comment: From the cursor get the column you need to check, and...check it. If you're not familiare with it take a look at http://www.higherpass.com/android/tutorials/accessing-data-with-android-cursors/2/ or just google it there's a lot of tuts.

Comment: is your cursor holding any value that differentiate that is it for homework or test?

Comment: Yes, in my cursor I have a lot of values, but one of them is to check if it's homework or test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to check that in bindview method

```
@Override
public void bindView(View view, final Context context, final Cursor cursor) {
    super.bindView(view, context, cursor);

    LinearLayout root_view = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.item_root);

    root_view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            //method
        }
    });

   final int position = cursor.getPosition();

    cursor.moveToPosition(position);

    int devoir = cursor.getInt(3);
    int evaluation = cursor.getInt(4);
    CheckBox cbdevoir = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.CBDevoir);


    if(devoir==1)
    {
     cbdevoir.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else{
    cbdevoir.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    }
```

Comment: Can you check my question please ? I've updated it with what I've done, it seems correct for me but can you confirm ? also, the row 3 from my database is Homework and the 4 is  Test

Comment: as per your edit i can see two diff value for homework  and test, what are the possibilities that if homework and test can be at the same time?

Comment: Well, when I create a Note, I check which RadioButton is selected. The one who's selected get the value 1 in my db's row. The other one gets 0.  So I can't have homework and test at the same time

Comment: check edited answer as per your note there will be any one so you can add condition as in answer

Comment: Ok, its working ! Yeah, kinda useless the second if that I wrote, thank you !!

Answer (score 1):

Your condition is not OK. In your adapters `bindView()` method:

**Use:**

```
if(devoir == 1) {
    cbdevoir.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} else {
    cbdevoir.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

**Instead of:**

```
if(devoir==1)
{
    cbdevoir.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
if(evaluation==1)
{
    cbdevoir.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: Yes, thank you for the advice ! I changed it iy my code !

Answer (score 0):

Steps

1. In XML row make checkbox is hide

android:visibility="gone"

2. In bindview method

   ```
   @Override

       public void bindView(View view, final Context context, final Cursor cursor) {


           super.bindView(view, context, cursor);

       LinearLayout root_view=LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.item_root);

   root_view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {

           //method
       }
   });


   CheckBox cbdevoir = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.CBDevoir);

   If(type.equals("Homework"){

     cbdevoir.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
    }
   else{

       cbdevoir.setVisibility(View.GONE);
   }


   if(cbdevoir.isChecked())
   {
       //method to set the homework done
   }
   else
       {
           //method to set the homework undone
       }
   }
   ```